# is it possible to not display the video feed when using the mediapipe library?

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence, mediapipe

I am attempting to only display the landmarks and 2d illustrations without the video feed behind them but to no avail. This seems like it should I have a very simple answer but I am lost. Does anyone have an idea on how to go about doing this?

```
    #dependencies
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#mediapipe instance
with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame.flags.writeable = False
        
        #make detection
        results = holistic.process(frame)

        #render detections
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, results.face_landmarks, mp_holistic.FACE_CONNECTIONS, 
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(256, 256, 256), thickness=1, circle_radius=1),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(256, 256, 256), thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
                                 )
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, results.pose_landmarks, mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(256, 256, 256), thickness=1, circle_radius=1),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(256, 256, 256), thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
                                 )
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, results.right_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS, 
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(256, 256, 256), thickness=1, circle_radius=1),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(256, 256, 256), thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
                                 )
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, results.left_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS, 
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(256, 256, 256), thickness=1, circle_radius=1),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(256, 256, 256), thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
                                 )
        
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi @aidan.goetzinger :) welcome to stackoverflow. I think you should just remove the cv2.imshow('frame', frame) line

Comment: or you can make an empty image, draw landmarks and show that instead of frame :)

Answer (score 1):

1. load a picture with a blank background (size it to camera feed size e.g. 1280x720 and give it a name e.g. blank_bg

`blank_bg = cv2.imread("image")`

2. In the mp_draw functions replace 'frame' with 'blank_bg.

> ```
> mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(blank_bg, results.face_landmarks, mp_holistic.FACE_CONNECTIONS, 
>                          mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(256, 256, 256), thickness=1, circle_radius=1),
>                          mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(256, 256, 256), thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
>                          )
> ```

3. Lastly ...

`cv.imshow("frame",blank_bg)`